# Hash Sum Mismatch for microsoft packages on ubuntu 16 server

Tags: ubuntu, package, ubuntu-16.04, apt, apt-get

I am getting the following error while running apt update:

`E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2  Hash Sum mismatch`

`E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Before someone thinks that this is already answered, I have tried all solutions which are given but none of them worked:
Solutions I tried :

```
#solution1
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update

#solution2
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update

#solution3
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order::=gz

#solution4
sudo sed -i -re 's/\w+\.archive\.ubuntu\.com/archive.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: Kindly refer to this https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth any answers there that are *not* in Ashwani's list of "solutions I tried"? I am also suddenly seeing this error when building docker images from a Dockerfile which worked just a few days ago.

Comment: Certainly worth pointing out that the packages were updated overnight - https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via Microsoft support, they identified a problem with their linux repo.  It has since been fixed/rolled back.  I was experiencing the same issue, but now it is working for me again.

Comment: When did they fix it? They introduced this issue yesterday.

Comment: I checked and confirm that the issue has been resolved from Microsoft.
@ponolson Thanks